# Angular8 как призвязать елементы к FormControl из FormArray

Tags: typescript, angular4, angular-material

Подскажите как привязать `<input matInput value="{{control.value['label']}}">` и `<mat-select>` к `FormControl`. Я думал может быть как-то  `<input matInput value="{{control.value['label']}}" [formControl]="Но что должно быть тут имя инстанса?Как указать тут номер">`

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zlgwzb)

Или необходимо присвоить `formControlName`? Но каким образом если в Array просто обьекты?

Comment: пример, который ты привел - это конечно хорошо. Но распиши, пожалуйста, задачу. Мне непонятно, что ты делаешь и какой результат ты хочешь достичь. Я могу кратко ответить, что, да, нужно использовать `formControlName`, но вряд ли это принесет тебе какую-то пользу в решении задачи

Answer (score 2, accepted):

насколько я вас понял вам необходимо сделать следующее:

```
<div formArrayName="dates"> //dates это название вашего FormArray control-a
    <div *ngFor="let date of dates; index as group;" [formGroupName]="group">//тут указываем индекс группы
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" formControlName="name"/> //тут указываем имя formControl-a
    </div>
</div>
```

Структура самого FormArray выглядит следующим образом:

```
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
new FormArray(arr.map(v => new FormGroup({
        name: new FormControl(v, [Validators.required])
    })));
```